# Как с помощью sql соединить два запроса с AVG для 2-х разных дат?

Tags: sql, запрос, таблицы, union, подзапрос

У меня есть 2 таблицы t1 и t2. Чтобы получить среднюю зарплату для каждого сотрудника в Марте пишу этот код.

```
select   t2.name,
    avg (t1.salary) as avg_salary_march
from     t1
join     t2 on t1.operator_name = t2.name 
where    date between '2023-03-01' and '2023-04-01'
group by t2.name
```

Но теперь мне надо сделать так, чтобы одновременно получить среднюю зарплату для каждого сотрудника за Март и Апрель и получить таблицу типа:

| name | avg_salary_march | avg_salary_april |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 200 |

Пыталась написать код используя подзапросы:

```
select  t2.name,

      (select avg(salary) as avg_salary_march
       from t1
       where date between '2023-03-01' and '2023-04-01'),     

      (select avg(salary) as avg_salary_april
       from t1
       where date between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-30')

from     t1
join     t2 on t1.operator_name = t2.name 
where    date between '2023-03-01' and '2023-04-30'
group by t2.ldap
```

Но в итоге получаю среднюю зарплату не для каждого сотрудника отдельно, а общее среднее значение за Март и общее среднее значение за Апрель.

Хочу показать 2-ой вариант(рабочий), где я использовала UNION:

```
select t2.name,
       avg (t1.salary) as avg_salary_march  
from   t1 
join   t2 on t1.operator_name = t2.name 
where  date between '2023-03-01' and '2023-04-01'
group by t2.name 

union all 

select t2.name,
       avg (t1.salary) as avg_salary_april
from   t1
join   t2 on t1.operator_name = t2.name 
where  date between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-30'
group by t2.ldap
```

Результат этого запроса не удовлетворил меня тем, что не получила значения за Март и за Апрель в отдельных столбцах и получила такой result:

| name | avg_salary_march |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| A | 200 |

Нужен совет, какой код мне написать, чтобы получить результат как в первом примере?
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: укажите свой SQL сервер

Comment: postgre-sql, dbeaver

Comment: попробуйте с помощью crosstab

Comment: к сожалению, я не имею опыта работы с crosstab, можете подсказать какой запрос могу написать?

Comment: посмотрите примеры: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_crosstab.html

Comment: *where    date between '2023-03-01' and '2023-04-01'* захватывает и данные за 1 апреля - хреновое, прямо скажем, среднее за март получается...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina 
нет 1 апреля он не берет, я все проверяла!

Comment: Пффф... добавьте запись за 1 апреля на 0 часов 0 минут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условное агрегирование.

```sql
select   t2.name,
    avg(CASE WHEN date between '2023-03-01' and '2023-03-31' THEN t1.salary END) as avg_salary_march,
    avg(CASE WHEN date between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-30' THEN t1.salary END) as avg_salary_april
from     t1
join     t2 on t1.operator_name = t2.name 
where    date between '2023-03-01' and '2023-04-30'
group by t2.name
```

Если за какой-то месяц данных нет - ожидаемо вернётся NULL.

Comment: все идеально работает, спасибо огромное!